# How to efficiently move many roots of hair back to the emitting mesh?

Tags: particles, hair, snapping

As shown on the screenshot, many roots of the hair are moved out of the emitting mesh. Now I want to move them back the emitting mesh, and how do I do that efficiently please?

I can comb each root one by one into the emitting mesh by using the Snap tool located on the top of screenshot. But I don't think this is an efficient method.

An efficient method would be using a "Shrinkwrap-like" modifier to project every root into the emitting mesh all by one shot.

[image]

By the way, the extra icons on the left side of the screenshot are from a paid add-on "3D hair brush".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press *Disconnect Hair*:

[image]

Then *Connect Hair*:

[image]

These will connect hair to the nearest surface point

Comment: What a life saver!