# Only select those hair roots which do not connect to the emitting mesh

Tags: particles, hair, selection-tools

In the *Particles Edit* mode, it is easy to select all hair roots. However, as the following screenshot shows, some hair roots are not connected to the emitting mesh. So how to quickly and only select those hair roots which are not connected to the emitting mesh please?

[image]

Comment: You can disconnect hair and then connect it again to make hair starts from the surface.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your meaning. If you know the answer, please post your answer in detail so that I can understand. Thanks!

Comment: It is not the answer, but you can connect hair back to surface.

Comment: @Crantisz you sound like you know the answer to this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270237/how-to-efficiently-move-many-roots-of-hair-back-to-the-emitting-mesh